# How to create a BOOLEAN column in MySql using Eclipselink

Tags: mysql, jpa, eclipselink

In my @Entity class I have defined a boolean property named *reservable*:

```
    @Column(name="reservable", columnDefinition = "boolean default true")
    private boolean reservable;
```

It is always a column of type TINYINT(1) with default value 1 created. How can I tell Eclipselink to generate a table column of type BOOLEAN in MySql?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

MySQL (5.x) doesn't know about a BOOLEAN type.

See for example http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/numeric-type-overview.html

Quote:

> BOOL, BOOLEAN
>
> These types are synonyms for TINYINT(1). A value of zero is considered false. 
>   Nonzero values are considered true.